# Getting information from an Array with Strings and Integer Values as Strings by Size of Integer Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, max, parseint

Let's say you have an array that looks like this:

```js
arr = ['Steve', '80000', 'Jen', '90000', 'Bob', '40000']
```

Where `arr[0]` and `arr[2]` are the names of employees and `arr[1]` and `arr[3]` are their salaries.

How would you go about writing a function that would return the name of the person with the largest salary?

In the example above we'd look for the function to return `'Jen'` because she has the highest salary.

My initial thought would be to turn all the values in the array to integers using `parseInt()`, finding the maximum value and then pointing to the value of the index before that maximum value but am having trouble writing a correct solution for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"I am having trouble writing..."*: please provide your code and show where your trouble starts.

Answer (score 0):

[Chunk function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456644/4481312)

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'chunk', {value: function(n) {
    return Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(this.length/n)), (_,i)=>this.slice(i*n,i*n+n));
}});
```

Then we can easily process [Name, Salary] pairs like,

```
["a", "11", "b", "12", "c", "3"]
  .chunk(2)
  .sort((p1, p2) => parseInt(p2) - parseInt(p1))[0]
```